# Distances over a rectangular parallelepiped

Tags: geometry, puzzle, solid-geometry

It is given a rectangular parallelepiped $3\times4\times5$. Which are the farthest points from a given vertex, provided one can only walk on the surface of the parallelepiped?

[Edit, for clarification]

The farthest point is not the opposite vertex, which has a distance equal to $\sqrt{74}\approx8.6$, as one can see looking at the following picture:

[image: A counterexample to the fact that $AF$ is the shortest path]

If one take a point $R$ which lies $0.3$ to the left of $F$ and $0.1$ above $F$, the distance $AR$ is equal to $\sqrt{\dfrac{757}{10}}\approx8.7$, greater than $AF$.

Besides, the other path along the $4\times5$ and the $3\times4$ faces, which leads to point $S$, is even longer.

I think that the point that I'm searching for should have the property that $AS=AR$ (and, of course, that $AR$ should be maximal).

Comment: It's not important, you can turn the parallelepiped as you like (it is rectangular, so 3, 4 and 5 are the lengths of its edges)

Comment: Draw the plane development of your parallelepiped and figure out the solution by yourself.

Comment: Note that the region $CFGH$ and $BIJHNM$ should not be the part of the net.  You miss the so-called **farthest shortest path** (I don't like this term.) should be $\sqrt{3^2+(4+5)^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

The **farthest spatial point** from one vertex is at the other end of the **space diagonal** which has a distance of $\sqrt{3^2+4^2+5^2}=\sqrt{50}$.

There's only **shortest path** along the surface of a cuboid among these two points.  By drawing a net of the cuboid, you can see how to find it out.

[image]

The shortest path is the minimum among the following:

$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+2bc} \, , \; \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+2ca} \, , \; \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab}$$

That is $\sqrt{5^2+4^2+3^2+2(3)(4)}=\sqrt{74}$

By the way, the **spatial distance** never exceeds the **surface distance**.

Comment: In the original problem (which had a $1\times1\times2$ cuboid), the opposite vertex is _not_ the farthest point. I'm trying to figure out if in this cuboid one can find a similar situation.

Comment: Be careful about **opposite** means.  For $1\times 1\times 2$ cuboid, say with vertices $V=\{(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1)$, $(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1)$, $(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},1)$, $(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},1)$, $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},-1)$, $(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},-1)$, $(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},-1)$, $(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},-1)\}.\,$  For any **opposite points** $A(x,y,z)$, $A'(-x,-y,-z)\in V$ forms a space diagonal.  One may say a cuboid, in general, has $D_{2h}$ symmetry.  See [this](http://home.kpn.nl/turing/cuboid_xxx.jpg) also.

Comment: I agree, but with definition of opposite, in a $1\times1\times2$ cuboid, the opposite vertex is not the farthest. Take a look at this image: http://imgur.com/B00N33R The distance $AP$ is greater than $AB$, if $P$ is at distance $1/4$ from the edges.

Comment: For example: if you take a point which is $3/10$ to the right of $P$ and $1/10$ below (take $Q(5.3,6.9)$), its distance from $O$ is equal to $\sqrt{757/10}$, which is approx. $8.7$, so greater than $\sqrt{74}$. So I would like to find the farthest point, which seems to me very elusive.

Comment: The **surface distance** can be as large as you want: if you choose a zig-zag path or even a [fractal path](https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-2473036ab599fd228cd2f0fd8d8ffe3f-c?convert_to_webp=true).

Comment: I choose the shortest path!

Comment: You should pay attention about the **spatial** versus **surface path**.  Also from which to which.  When we study **geodesics** for curved surfaces.  For example, minor arc of a great circle on a sphere is the absolute shortest (surface) path while major arc of that great circle is local minimum only.

Comment: I think that the path I draw from point $A$ to point $R$ is the shortest surface path from those two points. So I have shown that the farthest point from $A$ is not $F$. I'm looking for the farthest point from $A$, using only absolute shortest surface paths.

Comment: See my updated picture.

Comment: I see. Perhaps we are talking about two different things. I can see, in your picture, that the shortest distance from $O$ to an _opposite vertex_ is obtained by following the $OP$ path: I agree with your solution. But $P$ is not the farthest point from $O$, as I showed with my picture. I found another point, which has the shortest path of length $8.7$. Don't you agree?

Comment: My largest value is $\sqrt{90} \approx 9.487$.  Note that $P$, $P'$ and $P''$ become the same vertex after the net has been glued.

Comment: Note that the largest circle in the picture cover all the area of the net.  Why don't you use a piece of paper to fold up your own cuboid?

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 different ways to get from the corner to a point in the opposite small face, as shown in the picture below. Note that the way described by AN, going *below* the cube, is a shorter way to get to your R/S point in the question, and that point is actually worse than the corner.

[image]

For an AxBxC cuboid, if we denote the starting corner as (0,0,0), the opposite corner as (C,B,A), and our target point as (C, B-x, A-y), we have the distances:

$AG = (C + A - x)^2 + (B - y)^2 \\
AJ = (B + A - x)^2 + (C + y)^2 \\
AV = (A - x)^2 + (C + B - y)^2 \\
AN = (C + x)^2 + (A + B - y)^2$

Therefore our optimal point is either the opposite corner, or a point on one of the lines determined by two of the above distances being equal. I recommend you check all lines by yourself to check my answer, but I found that for the specific case of the 3x4x5 cuboid the optimal point is, indeed, the opposite corner.